# Base64.encode returns strange string

Tags: java, base64

I am running this code in Java 11:

```
String password = "Password123";
String encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(password.getBytes()).toString();
System.out.println("Encoded: " + encoded);
```

The output I am getting is `Encoded: [B@46f5f779` which is clearly incorrect.

Default charset is UTF-8.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Encoded: [B@46f5f779` is the reference to your object in-memory. Follow @ernest_k's answer for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String password = "Password123";
    String encoded = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(password.getBytes()));
    System.out.println("Encoded: " + encoded); // Encoded: UGFzc3dvcmQxMjM=
```

The reason why you get strange string is that you are actually calling byte[].toString(). Instead, you should create a string from the content of the byte array.

Answer (score 4):

You can encode directly to string using `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString`:

```
String encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder()
                                 .encodeToString(password.getBytes());
```